# Windows route two logical networks on one NIC

Tags: windows-server-2003, networking, routing

I have a Windows 2003 server which has one NIC with two networks configured on it.  There are two logical networks sharing the same layer 2 domain.

How do I configure the server to route traffic between the two logical networks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for Routing and Remote Access under Admin Tools.

Start up that and start the Configure and Enable Routing Wizard.

I believe you want to select Custom and LAN routing.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a good hit:
https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5844624.html